# Save the output of a trained pytorch neural network in .ark format

Tags: python, pytorch, kaldi

I am training my acoustic model which is multilayer DNN written in PyTorch. I want to save the output of the network as (.ark) file to use it in the decoding stage for automatic speech recognition. I searched a lot but can't find a function to do this. Any Help !!!

Comment: ark is format for features and other data files, not for neural network models. You probably want to do something else

Comment: I want to save the network output in a stdout file so is there is a function for this or can you tell me if I have a tensor how can I save this tensor in .ark file format

Comment: kaldi-io python package should be able to do that